# I cannot figure out why JPA is not able to generate Match table

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have no idea why this class is not working with JPA. Must be something regarding annotations I have chosen.
I'm trying to create a football match that happens on a date, in a specific field, with users with differents roles.

```
@Entity
public class Match {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    @Column(name = "user")
    private List<User> players;

    @OneToMany
    @Column(name = "user")
    private List<User> administrators;

    @OneToOne
    private User owner;

    @OneToOne
    private Field field;

    private Calendar calendar;

    public Match(User owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.administrators = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(owner));
        this.players = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(owner));
    }

   // getter and setters
}
```

Comment: Well, you seem to have two columns named "user": `players` and `administrators`. Not sure how JPA handles situations like that. Also, I don't think you're supposed to use `Column` annotations with fields annotated with [`OneToMany`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html).

Comment: changed to different names and still not working

Comment: thank you for your time. I removed @Column and nothing

Comment: FIELD and MATCH are reserved words in SQL

Comment: Your `Calendar` needs an `@Temporal` annotation and your `Match` entity requires a default constructor.

Comment: make sure you have same table use in your DB if not then you have to use @table(name=)  in your entity

Answer (score 0):

First remove the @Column annotations they are useless on @OneToMany.

Then you don't have a default constructor. This is required by JPA to constructor objects.

So your class should look like:

```
@Entity
public class Match {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<User> players;

    @OneToMany
    private List<User> administrators;

    @OneToOne
    private User owner;

    @OneToOne
    private Field field;

    private Calendar calendar;

    public Match() {
    }

    public Match(User owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.administrators = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(owner));
        this.players = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(owner));
    }

    // getter and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Class.....

```
@Entity
public class Match {

private Integer id;
private List<User> players;
private List<User> administrators;
private User owner;
private Field field;
private Calendar calendar;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "<variable name in user Class>", targetEntity = User.class)
public List<User> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(List<User> players) {
    this.players = players;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "<variable name in user Class>", targetEntity = User.class)
public List<User> getAdministrators() {
    return administrators;
}

public void setAdministrators(List<User> administrators) {
    this.administrators = administrators;
}

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
public User getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(User owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fieldId")
public Field getField() {
    return field;
}

public void setField(Field field) {
    this.field = field;
}

@Column(name ="calender")
public Calendar getCalendar() {
    return calendar;
}

public void setCalendar(Calendar calendar) {
    this.calendar = calendar;
}
```

}